# Symmetric properties of eigen vectors from symmetric properties of matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetry

In my physical problem I have a matrix:

$\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & -c_0 & -i b_1 & -c_1 \\
 a_0 & 0 & a_1 & ib_1 \\
 ib_1 & -c_1 & 0 & -c_0 \\
 a_1 & -i b_1 & a_0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

All symbols are reals, $i^2=-1$. The matrix has four eigenvalues satisfying $\lambda_1=-\lambda_2$ and $\lambda_3=-\lambda_4$, this can be shown symbolically.

It is **seems** that eigenvectors, corresponding to eigenvalues with the same absolute values, have the following properties so:
$V_1 = [v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4]$ and $V_2 = [-v_3,-v_4,-v_1,-v_2]$ (and the same for $V_3$ and $V_4$) in orthonormal basis.

I tried to proof it with Mathematica without any luck. I made lots of numerical calculations with different values of parameters and my assumption was always valid.

**Is it possible to prof it?**

Moreover, it seems that this property is valid for matrices with higher dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the negative signs in $V_2$ are not important. Now consider

$$
J =\pmatrix{0&0&-1&0\\0&0&0&1\\-1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0}$$
If you call the original matrix $A$ then you get
$$
A V_1 = \lambda_1 V_1 \Leftrightarrow
-J^{-1} A J \left(J^{-1}V_1\right) = -\lambda_1 J^{-1} V_1
$$

Your result follows from the observation that
$$
A = -J^{-1} A J $$
Hence $-\lambda_1$ is an eigenvalue with eigenvector $J^{-1} V_1$. This answers your question.

**Note:** In my original answer I had $J$ in the place of $J^{-1}$. For this matrix the two are the same, so the answer was technically correct. I just fixed in the interest of correctness.

Comment: You mean $A=-J^{-1}AJ$